Multiple graph from multiple data stream gets updated by one input control or control
I am using lens to create different graph from different data streams. They share common fieldname, say created_by. When I create input control or control (Kibana version 8.3.3), it updates all the graph if the fieldname is common. If the fieldname is not there in a datastream, it does not update. I do not want to update all the graph, only update the graph that has same data stream as control or input control. Is there any solution or workaround for that?
